# useColorMode imported from Theme UI plugin in React-based GatsbyJS doesn't work due to "InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby, theme-ui

- I am using [@smakosh](https://github.com/smakosh)'s GatsbyJS theme and [Theme UI](https://github.com/system-ui/theme-ui) plugin;
- I learned to use Hooks' `useColorMode` from [Hooks - `useThemeUI` and `useColorMode`](https://github.com/system-ui/theme-ui/blob/master/packages/docs/src/pages/hooks.mdx);
- My whole code is totally correct;
- I have already cleared the caches of GatsbyJS, npm and browser, but the same errors still persist;
- You can get my small package to analyse: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SsgPXAq9zMv8Yp4XDjy3MJLeWun-J3UQ/view?usp=sharing.

After compiling, I received two errors:

- `TypeError: setMode is not a function`;
- `InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character`:

[image]

Check my whole code:

```
/** @jsx jsx */

import { jsx, Styled, useColorMode } from 'theme-ui'
import { Context } from '../../common'
import SelectLanguage from './SelectLanguage'
import { Navegador, Input, Label, Submenu, StyledHeader } from './styles'

function Header() 
{
  const themes = ['deep', 'funk', 'future', 'swiss'];
  const modes = ['default', 'dark'];
  const [mode, setMode, setTheme, theme] = useColorMode()
  
  return (

    <Styled.root>
      <Context.Consumer>
        {({ toggleLanguage, lang }) => (
          <StyledHeader>
            <Navegador id="menu">
              <li>
                  <SelectLanguage lang={lang} toggleLanguage={toggleLanguage} />
              </li>

              <li>
                <Input id="modes" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
                <Label for="modes">Modes</Label>
                <Submenu className="submenu">
                  <li onClick={e => setMode("default")}> Light </li>
                  <li onClick={e => setMode("dark")}> Dark </li>
                </Submenu>
              </li>

              <li>
                <Input id="themes" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
                <Label for="themes">Themes</Label>
                <Submenu className="submenu">
                  <li onClick={e => setTheme("deep")}> Deep </li>
                  <li onClick={e => setTheme("funk")}> Funk </li>
                  <li onClick={e => setTheme("future")}> Futuristic </li>
                  <li onClick={e => setTheme("swiss")}> Swiss </li>
                </Submenu>
              </li>
              
            </Navegador>
          </StyledHeader>
        )}
      </Context.Consumer>
    </Styled.root>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the doumentation link you provided, the `useThemeUI` hook return value seems to contain the `theme`, `components`, `colorMode` and `setColorMode` properties. You could use that hook instead of the `useColorMode` hook. And change your `mode` and `setMode` variables to `colorMode` and `setColorMode` respectively. This could solve the *"setMode is not a function"* problem while still giving you access to the theme property.

Same `setMode` problem could be the root cause of this `invalidCharacterError` you are getting. So resolving that problem could also cause this error to go away. Otherwise look into the character set you should be using. The most common one these days is utf8. If your application contains diacritics, umlauts, hieroglyphics e.t.c., you might have to use the appropriate character set for that use-case.

Also do verify that `setTheme` is a valid property of the `useThemeUI` hook's return value. Much like the `setMode`, it was not mentioned in the documentation you provided. It is likely not to exist.

Comment: I am very sorry for my absence and still for my mistake. I made a mistake because I forgot of updating the file link because the site expired the share link. I switched to Google Drive. Please check the link again. Actually, `setColorMode` and `setMode` are variables. One is for colours switcher and another for dark and light modes.

Comment: No worries, could you load it up into codesandbox.io? It would be easier to replicate and debug that way if need be.

Comment: here is https://codesandbox.io/s/i81n-smakosh-6hm01.

Comment: The application is not loading. Codesandbox is producing this error: "Could not fetch dependencies, please try again in a couple seconds: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". Do you happen to know which dependencies they might be?

Comment: I chose the wrong sandbox, because it was React-based. I forked the Gatsby-based sandbox and it worked. Strange, it worked on CodeSandbox, because it revealed it was `setTheme`. You were right. I changed `setTheme` to `setMode`. It worked. But it did not work locally, it gave the same error. I leave you with https://codesandbox.io/s/i81n-smakosh-gatsby-7q476. I think better you test and discover locally.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll take a look. As for it not working locally, caching is most likely the cause. Check if the code version with your latest changes is running in your browser. If not, either hard-refresh the browser page; clear your browser cache and try again; or flush out your gatsby cache, take a clean build and hard-refresh the browser page again.

Comment: I cleaned the caches twice and it still gave the same errors. I suspect it be some version.

Comment: Yes, it could be very well be dependency version mismatch. Were you able to resolved it after matching up the dependencies in both environments?